# TSQL Get rows with a certain time for each day

Tags: sql, t-sql, networking

I am looking for a TSQL query that can return just a single record per day; For example if I had the following data I would want to just return the entry at 01:59:00 for each day; note that I don't really want to provide the seconds as it could sometimes be 01:59:03 or something like that so preferably 01:59

```
id      snapshotTime            name            code    total   onTime
1       2015-09-22 02:01:01     GB Railfreight  54      0       0
2       2015-09-22 02:00:01     GB Railfreight  54      0       0
3       2015-09-22 01:59:00     GB Railfreight  54      78      70
4       2015-09-21 02:01:01     GB Railfreight  54      0       0
5       2015-09-21 02:00:01     GB Railfreight  54      0       0
6       2015-09-21 01:59:00     GB Railfreight  54      72      68
```

The results I want back would look like this

```
id      snapshotTime            name            code    total   onTime
3       2015-09-22 01:59:00     GB Railfreight  54      78      70
6       2015-09-21 01:59:00     GB Railfreight  54      72      68
```

So I would have one row per day with just the last entry in this case the last entry is added at 1:59 and then reset at 2:00 for another days results. This data is coming from network rail, hence why I cant just get the values at midnight; as data is stored from 02:00 to 02:00 the next day.

Would be great to get some help on this; many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working nicely with this

```
SELECT * FROM OperatorRTPPM
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(5),snapshotTime, 108) = '01:59'
AND snapshotTime > '2015-09-20' AND snapshotTime < DATEADD(d, 1, '2015-09-22 02:00')
AND code = 54
```

The important thing was to get the time at 01:59 and then just limit by the date range and train company code

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood correctly. You just want to return for each individual day. Any record that occurred prior to 02:00:00 each day.

See my working example below on how to do this. This example takes into account any scenario where there may be more than one record that occurs at 01:59:XX taking the last one that was entered:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('RailTimes', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE RailTimes

GO


CREATE TABLE RailTimes (
    Id INT,
    SnapshotTime DATETIME
)


INSERT RailTimes (Id, SnapshotTime)
    VALUES (1, '21 september 2015 02:00:00')
    , (2, '21 september 2015 01:59:02')
    , (3, '21 september 2015 01:59:05')
    , (4, '22 september 2015 01:59:00')
    , (5, '22 september 2015 02:00:02')

SELECT
    *
FROM (SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, SnapshotTime)) ORDER BY SnapshotTime DESC) MostRecentSnapshot
FROM RailTimes
WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, SnapshotTime) < 2) SnapShotTimes
WHERE MostRecentSnapshot = 1
```

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function, is essentially grouping each day together by using the following partition (which turns each snapshottime to a time of 00:00:00 so we can group the days together):

```
DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, SnapshotTime))
```

It then orders them by `DATETIME` (with the most recent time first). The `WHERE` clause then only returns the ones that occurred prior to 02:00:00.

In the outer query, we then say just return the most recent snapshot time:

```
WHERE MostRecentSnapshot = 1
```

So in my example, you can see that for the `21st September 2015`. The row with Id `3` is returned with the time `01:59:05` as it occurred the latest.

Comment: Thanks I like that you explained it; I got it working in the end with this SQL

SELECT * FROM OperatorRTPPM
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(5),snapshotTime, 108) = '01:59'
AND snapshotTime > '2015-09-20' AND snapshotTime < DATEADD(d, 1, '2015-09-22 02:00')
AND code = 54

So think I needed to get the time value of 01:59 and then find the range in the dates provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cast(dateadd(hour, -2, snapshotTime) as date)
                                order by snapshotTime desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The "trick" is to subtract two hours from the snapshot time and extract the date component.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES
    id,
    CAST(snapshotTime AS smalldatetime) AS snapshotTime,
    name,
    code,
    total,
    onTime
FROM RailTimes
ORDER BY
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER
        (PARTITION BY CAST(snapshotTime AS date) ORDER BY snapshotTime);
```